# how to subset and group with a loop in r?

Tags: r, loops, batch-file, plyr

Most of my questions are simply how to extract and organize data, with no prior training I apologize for my inability to clearly express what I want.  I wish I even knew how to phrase things to look them up in text books or on line.  Here's my question now:

I have a data frame of information which has a unique group id called ID, there are 153 unique ID's but I have >6,000 rows of information from those groups.

What I would like to do is take all the information from 2 groups at a time and write out a simple csv file with all of the associated information.  How will that work when there are an odd number of overall individuals (n = 153).

I thought something like this:

```
IDs = unique(dat$ID)
for (i in length(IDs)){
    IDgp = subset(dat, dat$ID==IDs[i] & dat$ID==IDs[i+1])
    write.csv(IDgp, paste(IDgp[i],".csv")
    i = i+2
    }
```

This does not work, and I am not sure how to get it to increase to the next "group of 2".  I know that for loops are clunky and I had thought maybe ddply might work or even a which command instead of subset.  As there are multitudes of ways to do things in R I am not sure what to even call what I want to do.  I think I have way over complicated it.

I've been searching for answers and came across this as a possiblity, but do not know how to get it to write the information for more than 1 group at a time AND I am unclear what the function(x) command is doing:

```
d_ply(dat, "ID", function(x)
     write.csv(x[i], file = paste(x$ID[i], ".csv")
     , row.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: Do you need to save data of all possible pairs of group ID in separate files?

Comment: I probably wouldn't approach it like this but you could use a while loop instead.

Comment: @DrDom No, not all possible pairs, just sequentially working down the list - producing a file with information from group 1&2 then a file from group 3&4 then from 5&6.

Comment: `rollapply` from the `zoo` package works well for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help. But I think there is a more elegant way to do this.

```
IDs = unique(dat$ID)
for (i in seq(1, length(IDs), 2)){
  write.csv(dat[dat$ID %in% IDs[i+c(0,1)], ], 
    paste(IDs[i], "_", IDs[i+1], ".csv", sep=""))
}
```

Edited to create sequence for full length of IDs

Comment: should `paste(IDgp[i]` be `paste(IDs[i]` or perhaps `paste(IDs[i], IDs[i+1]`? (p.s. somehow my edits weren't being saved - sorry for the second try)

Comment: Yes, really! I just copy-pasted original code. Thanks for correction.

Comment: @DrDom When I run this script, the files are empty.  they have the header the correct nomenclature, but nadda for data.

Comment: Try changing `dat$ID==IDs[i] & dat$ID==IDs[i+1]` to `dat$ID %in% IDs[i+c(0,1)]`

Comment: @DrDom Do I have to create an empty data frame before I even run the loop? Even when I simply run the line IDgp = subset(dat, dat$ID==IDs[i] & dat$ID==IDs[i+1]) and then type in IDgp it shows the col names but data <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: @Kerry, sorry, didn't include your name in the comment above. Please see it for a recommendation.

Comment: @BenBarnes THANKS that worked great!  I will have to look up what %in% does and i+c(0,1) because I don't understand either nor have seen either.

Comment: @BenBarnes It did have a problem that I sort of eluided to.  I have an odd number of groups (n=153) and it did not produce a file for the last group because there wasn't an even "pair".

Comment: @Kerry, I think that actually had to do with the for loop in which the sequence was truncated at 151 instead of 153. I'll take the liberty of suggesting an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that builds a matrix of the appropriate dimensions from your IDs, and then loops through them:

```
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:10, foo = runif(10))
#This will throw a warning if dimensions don't line up, not sure what you want to do with those
idpairs <- matrix(sort(unique(dat$id)), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
> head(idpairs,2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
a_ply(idpairs, 1, function(x) print(dat[dat$id  %in% x,]))
```

You'd obviously replace the `print` function above with whatever is appropriate for your purposes.